# iOS crash FigBaseObjectFinalize

Tags: ios, crash, core-media

I have a video editor app,recently I got crash message from log told me that the app crashed at InternalRemoteAssetNotificationQueue.I have not met this crash message before,want to know what kind of problem about this，are there any solutions to solve this?
update:this is the crash log I have got

```
Crashed: InternalRemoteAssetNotificationQueue
0  CoreMedia                      0x19580b4ec FigBaseObjectFinalize + 20
1  CoreFoundation                 0x192ee3a74 _CFRelease + 216
2  CoreFoundation                 0x192ee3a74 _CFRelease + 216
3  CoreMedia                      0x195823208 figDeferredPostNotification + 48
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x191dbd1c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x191dcb444 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x191dc09a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x191dcd38c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x191dcd0ec _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x191fc52c8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x191fc4db4 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: can you add your crash report

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the report is too long ,I don't know how to add it

Comment: I am seeing this same bug too. Here's my report http://crashes.to/s/14b43507c66